# Converting non-numeric values to numeric in some, but not all, columns in pandas dataframe using column numbers rather than column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume a pandas df with many columns.  I am trying to convert all non-numeric values into np.nan values using pd.to_numeric as specified below.  However, I do not want to apply this to the first two columns; rather, it would only be applied to all columns other than the first two.

For instance, assume the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Adam', 'Bob', 'Chuck', 'David'],
                   'color': ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow']
                   'number1': [50, 750, 'ad098', 'baseball'],
                   'number2': [25, 'text', 1000, '200']},
                  )
```

Generally, I would just call out the names of the two columns that should be excluded.  However, in this case, I am trying to create a framework that can be applied to any df regardless of the names of the columns.  Hence, I want to exclude the first two columns on the basis of their column numbers [0:1].

I am able to successfully convert all non-numeric values in all columns to np.nam using the following:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

However, when I try to exclude the first two columns using either of the two methods below, I get an error.

```
df = df[df.columns[2:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')]
```

gives the error: "AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'apply'"

```
df = df[df.iloc[:,2:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')]
```

gives the error:  "ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object"

Clearly I am doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what it is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

This reads as "replace the columns after the first two with those same columns after applying method X".

Writing `df[something]` is simply *selecting the columns* of `df` using the object `something` - a sequence of indices or column names, for example.

So when you write an expression like

```
df[df.iloc[:,2:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')]
```

your `something` is a DataFrame (the value returned from the expression `df.iloc[:,2:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`).

Effectively, you were confusing the values used to *select* columns with the values you wanted to *replace* those columns with.

Comment: It works!!!  Thank you very much!  I also really appreciate the clarification between selecting and replacing - that helps my understanding a lot.